# Groovy Json with grouby, sum, count with nested, merge & many collection?

Tags: json, groovy, collections, merge, nested

Given Json:

```
{
"products" : [
    {"id":"p1", "name" : "Baseball Cap", "price" : "19.95"},
    {"id":"p2", "name" : "Tshirt", "price" : "34.95"},
    {"id":"p3", "name" : "Tennis Shoes", "price" : "129.95"},
    {"id":"p4", "name" : "Jacket", "price" : "79.95"}
],
"orders" : [
    { 
        "id" : "or1",
        "items" : [
            {"productId" : "p2", "quantity":3},
            {"productId" : "p1", "quantity":1}
        ]
    },
    { 
        "id" : "or2",
        "items" : [
            {"productId" : "p3", "quantity":1}
        ]
    },
    { 
        "id" : "or3",
        "items" : [
            {"productId" : "p3", "quantity":1},
            {"productId" : "p1", "quantity":3}
        ]
    }
]}
```

Get by groovy 1. Name of the product, 2. Number of orders placed for that product, 3. Total dollars spent on that product across all orders. like the output:

```
+--------------+---------+------------+
| Product      |  Orders |      Total |
+--------------+---------+------------+
[Baseball Cap  ,    2    ,        79.8]
[Tshirt        ,    1    ,       104.9]
[Tennis Shoes  ,    2    ,       259.9]
[Jacket        ,    0    ,           0]
```

Answer (score 1):

I did this:

```
​import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
def url_Json = new URL("https://www.tailorsoft.co/sample.json")
 
// Print the table header
println "+--------------+---------+------------+";
println "| Product      |  Orders |      Total |";
println "+--------------+---------+------------+";


def result = json.orders.collectMany{ X->
    // collect returns a list of N (in this example, N=2) elements 
    // [ [ orders1: ..., productId1: ..., quantity1: ... ],
    //   [ orders2: ..., productId2: ..., quantity2: ... ] ]
    X.items.collect{ Y->
            // return in [ productId: ..., orders: ..., quantity: ... ]
        [ id: Y.productId, orden: X.id, quant: Y.quantity] 
    }
}.groupBy({ user ->
    // Group by id
    user.id
    }).sort().collect { k, v -> 
    // Sum Quantity by product 
    // Total Order by Product
    [id:k, OT:v.orden.size(), QT:v.quant.sum()]
}

//Merge collection 
def resultd = (json.products +  result).groupBy { it.id}
    .values()
    *.sum()
    .collect { it << 
    ['DT': (Double.parseDouble(it.price)*(it.QT?:0)).round(1) ] 
}

//Print the report
resultd.each{ F->
    println([ (F.name?:0).padRight(14), 
    (F.OT?:0).toString().center(8),
    (F.DT?:0).toString().padLeft(11)]) 
}​
```

If someone finds a better recursive solution, please add it to learn. Thank you!

Comment: `[k1: v1]+[k2: v2]` can be written as `[k1: v1, k2: v2]`

Comment: @cfrick, nice suggestion. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is shorter :-)

Summarize the orders first (as we don't care what the order id was), and then find the orders per product and sum it all up

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
def url_Json = new URL("https://www.tailorsoft.co/sample.json")
 
// Print the table header
println "+--------------+---------+------------+"
println "| Product      |  Orders |      Total |"
println "+--------------+---------+------------+"


def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(url_Json.text)

def orders = json.orders.items.flatten()
def summary = json.products.collect { p -> 
    def nOrders = orders.findAll { it.productId == p.id }.sum { it.quantity } ?: 0
    [ name: p.name, orders: nOrders, total: new BigDecimal(p.price) * nOrders ]
}
summary.each {
    println "|${it.name.padRight(14)}| ${it.orders.toString().center(8)}|${it.total.toString().padLeft(11)} |"
}
println "+--------------+---------+------------+";
```

Outputs:

```
+--------------+---------+------------+
| Product      |  Orders |      Total |
+--------------+---------+------------+
|Baseball Cap  |    4    |      79.80 |
|Tshirt        |    3    |     104.85 |
|Tennis Shoes  |    2    |     259.90 |
|Jacket        |    0    |       0.00 |
+--------------+---------+------------+
```

### Edit

Shorter still

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def url_Json = new URL("https://www.tailorsoft.co/sample.json") 
def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(url_Json.text)

println "+--------------+---------+------------+"
println "| Product      |  Orders |      Total |"
println "+--------------+---------+------------+"
def orders = json.orders.items.flatten()
json.products.each { p -> 
    (orders.findAll { it.productId == p.id }.sum { it.quantity } ?: 0).with { o ->
        println '| ' + p.name.padRight(13) +
                '| ' + o.toString().center(8) +
                '|' + (new BigDecimal(p.price) * o).toString().padLeft(11) +
                ' |'
    }
}
println "+--------------+---------+------------+";
```

Comment: it is a good use the functions flatten and findAll. Thanks!